yield from with a Generator class
Due to needing a self reference inside the generator I have Generator classes instead of generator functions. But I also want to use "yield from" like:
def gen1():
    yield "foo"

def gen2():
    t = gen1()
    yield from t
    yield "bla"

for i in gen2():
    print(i)

Is this the best way to simulate yield from with Generator classes?
from collections.abc import Generator

class Test(Generator):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 5;
        
    def send(self, *args):
        print(f"Test.send({args})")
        self.count -= 1
        if self.count == 0:
            raise StopIteration()
        return "foo"

    def throw(self, value):
        print(f"Test.throw({value})")

class Test2(Generator):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 5;
        self.test = Test()

    def send(self, *args):
        if self.test:
            try:
                return self.test.send(*args)
            except StopIteration:
                self.test = None
        print(f"Test2.send({args})")
        self.count -= 1
        if self.count == 0:
            raise StopIteration()
        return "foo"

    def throw(self, value):
        print(f"Test2.throw({value})")

test2 = Test2()
while True:
    res = test2.send("bla")
    print(f"res = {res}")

How would I do the same with inheritance including multiple levels of inheritance?
class Test2(Test): ...

Update:
For (multiple) inheritance the classes just need to use self.__count and self.test = Test() can become self.__parent = super(). So only the first part of the question remains unanswered.

Why aren't you implementing __iter__ and __next__ as well? Instances of Generator are supposed to be iterators with send and throw as well.

@chepner Because they aren't abstract in the abc.Generator

With inheritance you can yield from super(), e.g.:
from collections.abc import Generator


class Test(Generator):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 5

    def send(self, *args):
        print(f"Test.send({args})")
        self.count -= 1
        if self.count == 0:
            raise StopIteration()
        return "foo"

    def throw(self, value):
        print(f"Test.throw({value})")


class Test3(Test):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._test3_count = 5

        self.parent = super()

    def send(self, *args):
        if self.parent:
            try:
                return self.parent.send(*args)
            except StopIteration:
                self.parent = None

        print(f"Test3.send({args})")
        self._test3_count -= 1
        if self._test3_count == 0:
            raise StopIteration()
        return "bar"


test3 = Test3()
i = 0
while True:
    res = test3.send(f"bla {i}")
    print(f"res = {res}")
    i += 1

Prints:
Test.send(('bla 0',))
res = foo
Test.send(('bla 1',))
res = foo
Test.send(('bla 2',))
res = foo
Test.send(('bla 3',))
res = foo
Test.send(('bla 4',))
Test3.send(('bla 4',))
res = bar
Test3.send(('bla 5',))
res = bar
Test3.send(('bla 6',))
res = bar
Test3.send(('bla 7',))
res = bar
Test3.send(('bla 8',))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/script.py", line, in <module>
    res = test3.send(f"bla {i}")
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/script.py", line, in send
    raise StopIteration()
StopIteration


The part about the inheritance was more a question about both Testand Test2 using self.count and with multiple inheritance each level would use self.parent. They would interfere with each other. The solution there is to use self.__count and self.__parent.
